# Accessing the superview of the parentview controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, parentviewcontroller

I have a Viewcontroller A, I've added a Viewcontroller B as a subview. B has many childviewcontroller C,D,E. C,D,E are 3 UItableViewcontroller. This is what I'm trying I would like to segue from A to another viewcontroller F when pressed on C , D or E 's UitableViewcells.

First question: Is this the best way to do it?

Can you help Please?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the proper UIViewController containment functions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `NSNotificationCenter` and send a notification to the `UINavigationController` that has A and B in it.

Comment: I don't get it , basically I am trying to access the superview of the parentviewcontroller right? Can you give a sample code?

Comment: Basically, you add a superview or the unnavigationcontroller that  contains A and B as and `observer` for the `NSNotification` that you fire from an event (like didselectrow atIndexPath) in E. Is that clear, are you familiar with the NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: Basically, you add a superview or the unnavigationcontroller that contains A and B as... It seems like there is something missing

Comment: I finally used the nsnotification, its quite simple and it works thank you